# how to Round a value in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm learning database and I have a question,

When I run the following query to give me 12 month Average Salary,

```
SELECT `EmployeeNo`,(`Salary`/12,) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```

The salary that it returns is like 7787.000992213

How can i round the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the number truncated, do this, using `TRUNCATE`:

```
SELECT `EmployeeNo`,TRUNCATE((`Salary`/12,),0) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```

If you want it rounded to the nearest integer, do this, using `ROUND`:

```
SELECT `EmployeeNo`,ROUND(`Salary`/12,) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 1):

[ROUND(X), ROUND(X,D)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) - Rounds the argument X to D decimal places

For your example:

```
SELECT `EmployeeNo`, ROUND(`Salary`/12) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT `EmployeeNo`,ROUND(`Salary`/12,) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

The ROUND() function is used to round a numeric field to the number of decimals specified.

```
SELECT `EmployeeNo`, ROUND(`Salary`/12) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```

Rounding just means to round up from 5 or down from anything less. ROUND is unique because you can tell SQL which position you would like rounded

```
SELECT ROUND( 1 );   /* returns 1 */
SELECT ROUND( 1.5 ); /* returns 2 */
SELECT ROUND( 1.4635, 1 ); /* returns 1.5 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function:

```
SELECT 'EmployeeNo', ROUND('Salary'/12, 0) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```

Alternatively, since you don't need any decimal places, you can bypass the second argument:

```
SELECT 'EmployeeNo', ROUND('Salary'/12) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```

According to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round), the `ROUND()` function accepts two arguments: the first is the number to be rounded, and the second *optionally* specifies the decimal place to round to:

> ROUND(X), ROUND(X,D)
>
> Rounds the argument X to D decimal places. The rounding algorithm depends on the data type of X. D defaults to 0 if not specified. D can be negative to cause D digits left of the decimal point of the value X to become zero.

Answer (score 0):

Use round function [read here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_round.asp)

```
SELECT `EmployeeNo`, ROUND(`Salary`/12,0) as AverageSalary FROM Employee
```